# Batch file called from a c# application not getting executed via task scheduler

Tags: c#, batch-file, task, scheduler

I have a C# application which internally creates a batch file and runs it. When I run the exe manually, everything works fine, but when i run it via task scheduler, it fails to execute the batch file. (I'm using Windows 8). Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share some code. A priori, I don't see the exact point of creating a batch file at runtime; note that relative paths might be an issue while executing batch files.

Comment: As @peer mentiond, the working directory could be incorrect.  In addition there could be a permissions error - check what user the task is running as and make sure that user has access to the directory you are attempting to write the bat file to.  Also check that there are no commands in the bat file that the task user can not execute.

Comment: Possibly not a coding issue.  I had a similar system running on a server and this required specific permissions in order to allow the tasks launched .exe to execute a batch file.  Not posted this as an answer as I can't remember which permission it is specifically (yet).

Comment: Hi, relative paths were the issue. I had missed one in my code :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I guess the running directory is not correct. Your application creates the batch file on the wrong place or your application looks for the batch file on the wrong place. Check the running directory in the task scheduler to fix this.

Comment: Another thing to consider would be permissions: what identity is the exe running as? (Process Monitor can be extremely helpful with issues like this: set a filter with the name of the exe as the process name and see what's failing.)

Comment: hi Peer, the application works fine when i run it manually, like it fetches the batch file from the right place and works properly. The issue happens ONLY when it is run via task scheduler. Anyways let me check my code for relative paths.